# Can not replace a certain text in an html string with java

Tags: java, html, regex, expression, jakarta-mail

I have a method that suppose to replace part of an html string before sending it to clients email.
I have tried using **java replaceAll() method** but didnt succeed.
Here is what i tried so far:

```
data.replaceAll("dd%title%dd", "This is the Title");
data.replaceAll("dd%message%dd", "This is the message body");
```

but when i tried this it doesnt work and i keep getting the string without it been replaced.
Here is the image of the message i recieved in yahoo mail inbox:
[Yahoo mail screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asMlN.png)

I have tried using regex expression to replace but its not working as i expected.

**Here is what i have now**

```
/******************* CONSTRUCTING THE MESSAGE TRANSLATOR ********************/
    private String msgTranslate(String subject, String messaging){
        // HERE WE START CONSTRUCTING THE MESSAGE TRANSLATE
        String content="";
        String data="";
        DjadeUtil util=new DjadeUtil();
        // NOW LETS START PROCESSING
        if(messaging!=null && subject!=null){
            // Now lets read
            try {
                data=util.readByScanner(TEMPLATESOURCE);
                // Now lets check
                if(data.length()>0){
                    // Here we start matching to replace
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(data.length());
                    Pattern patA = Pattern.compile("dd%title%dd");
                    Pattern patB = Pattern.compile("dd%message%dd");

                    Matcher mA = patA.matcher(data);
                    Matcher mB = patB.matcher(data);

                    while (mA.find()) {
                        mA.appendReplacement(sb, subject);
                    }// End of while loop

                    while (mB.find()) {
                        mB.appendReplacement(sb, messaging);
                    }// End of while loop

                    //HERE WE STORE NEW CHANGE
                    mA.appendTail(sb);
                    mB.appendTail(sb);
                    content=sb.toString();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // Here we return string
        return content;
    }
```

**Here is my html String now**

```
<div style="line-height: 20px;">
                    <!-- THE BODY OF NEWSLATER GOES HERE //-->
                    <div class="newTitle">dd%title%dd</div>
                    <div class="newBody">dd%message%dd</div>
                    <div class="newButtons">
                        <button class="butNews" onclick="window.location='https://napoleoninvestment.net/?page_id=12'">Join our Telegram</button>
                        <button class="butNews" onclick="window.location='https://napoleoninvestment.net/?page_id=391'">Invest Now</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to replace "dd%title%dd" with "This is the Title" and "dd%message%dd" with  "This is the message body".
I don't know where an going wrong. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Although you have a working solution, not that this is a *bad way* to do things. The better option is to use a template engine, such as Thymeleaf (which understands HTML structure), or Velocity/Mustache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to reassign `data`. You don't need `replaceAll` since there is no need for regex match.

```
data = data.replace("dd%title%dd", "This is the Title");
data = data.replace("dd%message%dd", "This is the message body");
```

Comment: Oh yes i totally forgot